# Is there any reason to use "if not ***.filter().exists(): ***.create()" instead of "***.get_or_create()"?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I can not find the answer, would it be faster to use:

```
if not Model.objects.filter(*some_data*).exists():
    Model.objects.create(*some_data*)
```

then:

```
Model.objects.get_or_create(*some_data*)
```

Does anyone know?

Comment: so how did it go?

Comment: @e4c5 Unfortunately, I have no answer

Answer (score 1):

Well [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get_or_create) is

> A convenience method for looking up an object with the given kwargs
>   (may be empty if your model has defaults for all fields), creating one
>   if necessary.

So at the very least you are violating the DRY principal. Going beyond that you are checking for all the fields in the model not just the primary key or unique field. You are try to find an object where all the fields match. So chances are very high that you will get false results and your create statement will fail. That's why get_or_create has the `defaults` parameter

Comment: Does it invoke `UPSERT` sql command when available (e.g. when using postgresql)? 

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/UPSERT

Comment: No it doesn't AFAIK